# didSet not working on variable

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell, didset

I'm trying to pass data from my cellClass to a viewController. I can easily pass the label text from cellClass to vc but can't set the variable in vc.

This is my model class:

```
class Item: NSObject {

    var itemId: String?
    var itemLabel: String?
 }
```

Here's is my `didSelectItem` CellClass code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let item = item?[indexPath.item] {
            let vc = VC()
            vc.presentVC(launcher: vc)
            vc.item = item

            if let id = item.itemId {
                vc.itemId = id
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, `presentVC` is an extension that I have created to present the vc. And this is what I've written in my ViewController:

```
class VC: UIViewController {

    var itemId = String()

    let itemLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "TEST TEST TEST"
        return label
    }()

    var item: Item? {
        didSet {
            itemLabel.text = item?.itemLabel

            if let id = item?.itemId {
                itemId = id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So by doing this, I can get the itemLabel from the cellClass but the id is now getting set and showing `nil`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So somehow I fixed it! The thing is everytime I select the item on `didSelectItem` the `didSet` method is called. So I just created a method first like this:

```
func setupId(item: Item) {

        var itemId = String()

        if let id = item.itemId {
            itemId = id
        }

        print(itemId)
    }
```

And in the `didSet` I just added this function like this:

```
var item: Item? {
        didSet {
            itemLabel.text = item?.itemLabel
            if let item = item {
                setupId(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is pretty much the fix!